# What is the data type of text[i]?

Tags: c, split, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to count the number of words in a string entered by the user with this custom function:

```
int count_words(char* text)
{
   int wc = 0;
   for(int i = 0,k = strlen(text); i<k;i++)
   {
      if(strcmp(" ",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp(".",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp("!",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp("?",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp(",",text[i]) ==0)
      {
          wc++;
      }
   }
    return wc+1;
}
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
re.c:59:21: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
      if(strcmp(" ",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp(".",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp("!",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp("?",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp(",",text[i]) ==0)
                    ^~~~~~~
                    &

re.c:59:48: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
      if(strcmp(" ",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp(".",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp("!",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp("?",text[i]) ==0 || strcmp(",",text[i]) ==0)
                                               ^~~~~~~
                                               &
```

What is really happening?

Comment: The data type of `text[i]` is `char`, but `strcmp` takes two `const char *`, so you want to pass `text + i` or equivalently `&text[i]`, as the compiler is indeed suggesting you.

Comment: In any case, it looks like you are only comparing strings of one single character so you might as well check manually with `text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '.' || ...`. Your `strcmp` will always fail except in the case that the character is the last one of the string, because `strcmp` checks that the *whole* two strings equal each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp` takes `char *` (string) not a single `char`. It's better if you use strtok` to count the number of words in a string.

Here's a simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char arr[] = "Temp hello bye! No way. Yes";
  char *delimeters = " !.";

  char *token = strtok(arr, delimeters);
  int count = 0;

  while (token != NULL) {
    count++;
    token = strtok(NULL, delimeters);
  }
  printf("Words = %d", count);

  return 0;
}
```

You can use `strpbrk` instead of `strtok` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strcmp` is declared the following way

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

As you can see the both parameters of the function have the pointer type `const char *`.

But in this call of the function used by you

```
strcmp(" ",text[i])
```

the second argument has the type `char`. So the compiler issues the error message.

> error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to
> parameter of type 'const char *';

Also your function has logical bugs. For example for an empty string it returns the number of words equal to `1`.

```
return wc+1;
```

And each separator it counts as a word. So for a string that contains only separators the function interprets it as containing several words.

Apart from this the function  `count_words` shall not change the passed string. It should be declared like

```
size_t count_words( const char *text );
```

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t count_words( const char *text )
{
    const char *separators = " \t.,!?";
    size_t n = 0;
    
    while ( *text )
    {
        text += strspn( text, separators );
        
        if ( *text )
        {
            ++n;
            text += strcspn( text, separators );
        }
    }
    
    return n;
}


int main(void) 
{
    const char *text = "We, beginners, should help each other!";
    
    printf( "There are %zu words in the text \"%s\".", count_words( text ), text );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 6 words in the text "We, beginners, should help each other!".
```

A more general approach is when the user of the function can call it specifying by himself required separators of words. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t count_words( const char *text, const char *separators )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    while ( *text )
    {
        text += strspn( text, separators );
        
        if ( *text )
        {
            ++n;
            text += strcspn( text, separators );
        }
    }
    
    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *text = "We, beginners, should help each other!";
    
    printf( "There are %zu words in the string \"%s\".", count_words( text, " \t.,!?" ), text );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
There are 6 words in the text "We, beginners, should help each other!".
```

Answer (score 0):

strcmp takes an array of char which is end with NULL `'\0'`.
For your question, you need to increment number of words when you find your special characters.
and you should check there is no repeated special char respectively.

```
/*const special_char[] = {' ','.','!','?',','};*/

int count_words(char* text)
{
    uint32_t idx = 0;
    int wc = 0;

    /*if the first char equal one of special char, don't count that as word*/
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        /*Special char shouldn't be repeated respectively otherwise, don't count that as word*/
        if (
            ((' ' == text[i]) || ('.' == text[i]) || ('!' == text[i]) || ('?' == text[i]) || (',' == text[i]))
            && 
            ((' ' != text[i - 1]) && ('.' != text[i - 1]) && ('!' != text[i - 1]) && ('?' != text[i - 1]) && (',' != text[i - 1]))
        )
        {
            wc++;
        }
    }

    /*For the last word*/
    wc++;

    return wc;
}
```